# Generic type for typing vuex store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, vuex

I am trying to create a generic type which will prove typing hints for `Vuex` mutation. I read this article [Vuex + TypeScript](https://dev.to/3vilarthas/vuex-typescript-m4j) and I get inspired to create something more generic. I came up with something like this:

```js
export type MutationType<S, P, K extends keyof P> = Record<K, (state: S, payload: P[K]) => void>;

// S
export type DiceGameState = {
  round: number;
  score: number;
  diceItems: DiceHistoryItem[];
};

// P
export interface DiceGameMutationPayloadMap {
  INCREMENT_SCORE: number;
  DECREMENT_ROUND: number;
  ADD_DICE_HISTORY_ITEM: DiceHistoryItem;
}

// K
export enum DiceGameMutationsKeys {
  INCREMENT_SCORE = 'INCREMENT_SCORE',
  DECREMENT_ROUND = 'DECREMENT_ROUND',
  ADD_DICE_HISTORY_ITEM = 'ADD_DICE_HISTORY_ITEM'
}

export type DiceStoreMutation = MutationType<
  DiceGameState,
  DiceGameMutationPayloadMap,
  keyof typeof DiceGameMutationsKeys
>;

export const mutations: MutationTree<DiceGameState> & DiceStoreMutation = {
  DECREMENT_ROUND: (state: DiceGameState, payload: number) => {},
  INCREMENT_SCORE: (state: DiceGameState, payload: number) => {},
  ADD_DICE_HISTORY_ITEM: (state: DiceGameState, payload: DiceHistoryItem) => {}
};
```

Where:

- **`S`** → type of mutation state
- **`P`** → map of mutation name and type of payload assigned to this mutation
- **`K`** → mutation name

If I check details of this `MutationType` in my IDE I am getting this hint:

[image]

So the key in this object is one of `K` keys and the value is a method which takes state which is type of `S` and payload which is type of assigned value to `P`.

If I try to compile this code I am getting this error:

> Error:(7, 3) TS2322: Type '(state: DiceGameState, payload: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(state: DiceGameState, payload: number | DiceHistoryItem) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'payload' and 'payload' are incompatible.
> Type 'number | DiceHistoryItem' is not assignable to type 'number'.
> Type 'DiceHistoryItem' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Do you know how can I make my generic to work ?

### Example:

I want to let TS infer the type of payload for a given mutation name. For example if you have a mutation named `INCREMENT_SCORE` then the type of `payload` **hinted** by TS should be a number. This is the reason why I created this: `DiceGameMutationPayloadMap`, then after creating this `const mutations`. Typescript should tell me what type payload should have (basing on name of mutation).

A good example of this can be also typing for `addEventListenr` method provided by TypeScript. This type infers the type of **event** (`ev`) basing on a given **event name**(`type`):

```js
addEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: HTMLButtonElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
```

For more details about this type you should check [lib.dom.ts → line 6385](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L6385)

Comment: You specify two different types for mutation constants. It's suspicious! On which line does the error occur?

Comment: @RafaelPizao It is intersection type I did it purposely. I put an error message in description of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. It takes me some time to figure out what I am doing wrong but in the end I understood my mistake.

My first mistake was inside `DiceStoreMutation` because my 3rd argument of this generic referred to **type of the key** no key name. The proof of this we can see on attached screenshot:

[image]

We can see that **Expanded** shows that **`p`** is actually a string, but it should be a union of string Literals **`'ADD_DICE_HISTORY_ITEM' | 'DECREMENT_ROUND' | 'INCREMENT_SCORE'`**. You could think that maybe I just should use `keyof DiceGameMutationsKeys` instead of `keyof typeof DiceGameMutationsKeys` which will refer to keys names of this interface instead of types of keys, but this of course occurred an error as expected. It made me think that I should change my generic **`MutationType`** somehow. After I read @Joel Bourbonnais answers and check this [very good example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) about the `P[K]` part being a `Index types`. I came up with a new idea for my **`MutationType`**: `Mapped generics` + `Index types`.
This new type came up with this shape:

```js
export type MutationType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof U]: (state: T, payload: U[K]) => void;
};
```

And I can say only one thing *It works a treat*. Now I do not even need `DiceGameMutationsKeys` because `DiceGameMutationPayloadMap` provides all the information. You may ask why? I'm already rushing with an explanation:

- Firstly, `K in keyof U` so `K` can be only a key of `U` so it will be a union of sting literals of `U` keys interface.
- Secondly, `U[K]` so it will be a lookup for a type of `U` under the `K` key(one of this union of sting literals of `U` keys interface)

Below you can find a screenshot with proof:

[image]